# Как вернуть панель в Linux Mint Mate 17

Tags: linux, linux-mint

Включил компьютер, пропала панель.

Comment: https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?f=206&t=124839

Comment: Востонавил панельку. Она почему-то у меня удалилась, то есть её в системе не оказалось и я её по новому установил, выполнил sudo apt-get install mate-panel.

Comment: ps: странно, ничего серьёзного не устанавливал и изменений не делал, только Гугл хром устанавливал с оф сайта деб пакетом. Кстати, когда по новому сейчас установил панель "mate-panel", пропал браузер Гугл хром, ну и фиг с ним.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. для начала стоит убедиться, что пакет `mate-panel` установлен:

   ```
   $ dpkg --get-selections | grep mate-panel
   ```

   если вернёт что-то подобное:

   ```
   mate-panel                                 install
   ```

   значит пакет установлен. если не вернёт ничего или

   ```
   mate-panel                               deinstall
   ```

   то надо установить:

   ```
   $ sudo apt-get install mate-panel
   ```
2. если оказалось, что пакет установлен, можно попробовать (как советуют, например, [здесь](https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?f=206&t=124839)) выполнить команду:

   ```
   $ mate-panel --reset
   ```